Question about proof of Treewidth Duality Theorem in Diestel
I'm reading up on the Treewidth Duality Theorem in Diestel, which says that

$$bn(G) = tw(G) + 1.$$

$bn(G)$ here is the Bramble number of a graph $G$ and $tw(G)$ is the treewidth of $G$. My question is regarding this specific step of the proof, which I find I cannot move forward without understanding (Theorem 12.4.3, Page 356):

How does $T_1 \cap T_2 = \varnothing$ make sense? From my knowledge, $T_1$ and $T_2$ are auxiliary trees that do not interact with each other! It makes no sense to intersect them.
